# JOGL : my cube rotation speed is not regular

Tags: java, jogl

I've just written a simple animation in JOGL : a 6-colored cube spins around y axis. But it seems my animation has a little speed workaround : sometimes it accelerate, and sometimes it slows though i just call glRotate() with a float variable that I increment on each display call (my code is below).

- My processor is a pentium dual core t3400
- My operating system is Xubuntu 11.04 32 bits
- My graphic card is ATI Radeon HD4330 and i've installed a recent proprietary driver : 11.6 (downloaded on AMD website, not on ubuntu software manager)

In Eclipse EDI (I'm using Indigo 3.7.0), this is how i've set my user library :

- I've downloaded the JOGL 2.0 beta 23 (from 2011, march 03) for i586 linux
- In the user library I imported the following jars : newt.all.jar, nativewindow.all.jar, jogl.all.jar, gluegen-rt.jar
- All of the imported jars link to the lib subfolder of uncompressed jogl archive : where are all the *.so files

Here my three classes.

ArcballExperiment.java

```
package com.gmail.bernabe.laurent.jogl.arcball_experiment;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.jogamp.opengl.util.Animator;

public class ArcBallExperiment extends JFrame {

    public ArcBallExperiment(){
        setTitle("ArcBall Experimentation");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        GLCanvas glCanvas = new GLCanvas();
        TheGLEventListener glEventListener = new TheGLEventListener();
        glCanvas.addGLEventListener(glEventListener);
        add(glCanvas);

        final Animator animator = new Animator(glCanvas);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                animator.stop();
                System.exit(0);
            }


        });

        animator.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ArcBallExperiment().setVisible(true);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

Cube.java :

```
package com.gmail.bernabe.laurent.jogl.arcball_experiment;

import javax.media.opengl.GL2;

public class Cube {

    /**
     * Draws a cube in a GL2 context
     * @param gl - GL2 - GL2 context
     */
    public static void draw(GL2 gl){
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);

            // front : blue
            gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f);
            gl.glVertex3f(+0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f);
            gl.glVertex3f(+0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f);

            // back : green
            gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(+0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
            gl.glVertex3f(+0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);

            // left : red
            gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f);

            // right : orange
            gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(+0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f);
            gl.glVertex3f(+0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f);
            gl.glVertex3f(+0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f);
            gl.glVertex3f(+0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);

            // top : white
            gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(+0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f);
            gl.glVertex3f(+0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f);

            // bottom : yellow
            gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(+0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f);
            gl.glVertex3f(+0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f);

        gl.glEnd();
    }

}
```

TheGLEventListener.java :

```
package com.gmail.bernabe.laurent.jogl.arcball_experiment;

import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.gl2.GLUgl2;

public class TheGLEventListener implements GLEventListener {

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        glu.gluLookAt(
                0f, 0f, 3f,
                0f, 0f, 0f,
                0f, 1f, 0f
        );

        gl.glRotatef(rotationAngle, 0f, 1f, 0f);
        Cube.draw(gl);

        rotationAngle += 0.3f;
        if (rotationAngle >= 360f)
            rotationAngle %= 360f;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL2.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width,
            int height) {
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glViewport(x, y, width, height);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        glu.gluPerspective(60.0f, (float) width/height, 1f, 10f);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    }

    private GLUgl2 glu = new GLUgl2();
    private float rotationAngle = 0f;

}
```

I'm thinking it could be because I imported incompatible jars in the user library made for my JOGL eclipse projects, but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance

(The title ArcBall experiment seems inapropriated, and it's right : this cube spinning is juste a phase for me to remember again the JOGL programming before going to arcball implementation.)

Comment: Finally, it seems that the problem can be solved by forcing the FPS value : I replaced Animator by FPSAnimator => The cube rotation was not "buggy" any more.

Comment: Nice work Laurent BERNABE. Can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem :)
I changed the animator instance to FPSAnimator instead of Animator, in order to keep a constant FPS. There is just one class to update : 
ArcBallExperiment.java

```
package com.gmail.bernabe.laurent.jogl.arcball_experiment;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;

public class ArcBallExperiment extends JFrame {

    public ArcBallExperiment(){
        setTitle("ArcBall Experimentation");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        GLCanvas glCanvas = new GLCanvas();
        TheGLEventListener glEventListener = new TheGLEventListener();
        glCanvas.addGLEventListener(glEventListener);
        add(glCanvas);

        /*
         *  Here I limit the FPS to a quite lower value than default,
         *  thanks to the FPSAnimator class : 180 FPS here.
         *  That way, cube rotation speed will really be constant
         */
        final FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(glCanvas, 180);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                animator.stop();
                System.exit(0);
            }


        });

        animator.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ArcBallExperiment().setVisible(true);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```